# Is $\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \ge 0, v^Tx \le 1 \quad (\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert\lvert v \rvert\rvert = 1) \}$ a polyhedron?

Tags: linear-programming

I am working on the following exercise:

> Consider $$P := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x \ge 0,  v^Tx \le 1 \quad (\forall v \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lvert\lvert v \rvert\rvert = 1) \}$$
>
> Is $P$ a polyhedron?

I think that $P$ is not a polyhedron since there are infinitely many such $v$, so we may not express $P$ in terms of a matrix.

Could you please tell me if my reasoning works?

Comment: what is the meaning of $x\ge0$ when $x\in\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: That $x_1,x_2 \ge 0$.

Comment: OK, I think $P$ is one-fourth of a disk?

Comment: @CalvinKhor $v$ is probably a fixed vector... $v^T x \leq 1$ is a linear restriction.

Comment: @PierreCarre but $\forall v$ appears inside the definition for the set? so is it not the intersection over all such $v$?

Comment: You probably mean a polygon since polyhedrons are 3D objects (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron). Also note that $P$ can be unbounded, e.g. when $v = (-1,0)$

Comment: @CalvinKhor I believe that the definition of the set is not formally correct but the intention of the question is the one I mentioned.

Comment: @PierreCarre I guess, given the tag, your interpretation makes more sense!

Comment: @PierreCarre: Sorry, but the question is exaclty as I wrote it above.

Comment: I believe that $P$ as given above is not a polyhedron, but I do not see how to justify that $P$ can not be described via a matrix. I mean geometrically is clear since this quarter circle can not be described via finitely many halfspaces.

Comment: In that case @CalvinKhor is correct when he says that $P$ is a quarter of circle, and so not a polygon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the cases $v_1=0, v_2=1$ and $v1=1, v_2=0$, you see the $P \subseteq [0,1]\times[0,1]$. Additionally, we can show that, when $v_1^2+v_2^2=1$, the line defined by $v_1 x+v_2 y = 1$ is tangent to the unit circle, which leads to the conclusion mentioned by @CalvinKhor: $P$ is the parte of the unit circle in the first quadrant, and so not a polygon.